# regex: Match everything starting from A until, but not including, B

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a file with an input similar to this:

```
CQUAD4 123123 123 234
CQUAD4 123123 123 234
CQUAD4 123123 123 234
PCOMP 123 123 123 123
123 123 123 123 123
123 123 1231 23
CQUAD4 123123 123 234
CQUAD4 123123 123 234
CQUAD4 123123 123 234
CQUAD4 123123 123 234
CQUAD4 123123 123 234
PCOMP 123 123 123 123
123 123 123 123 123
123 123 1231 23
432 234 2342 34
CQUAD4 123123 123 234
CQUAD4 123123 123 234
CQUAD4 123123 123 234
CQUAD4 123123 123 234
```

I want to capture

```
PCOMP 123 123 123 123
123 123 123 123 123
123 123 1231 23
```

and

```
PCOMP 123 123 123 123
123 123 123 123 123
123 123 1231 23
432 234 2342 34
```

I currently have `PCOMP((.|\n)*)CQUAD4` but it captures everything, including the `CQUAD4` block in between. What should I use in order to match starting from `PCOMP`, up until the character before the next instance of `CQUAD4`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make your regex ungreedy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might get along with

```
PCOMP[\s\S]*?(?=CQUAD)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/2BAGib/1/).
`(.|\n)` is one of the most inefficient patterns you can think of, really.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `*?` quantifier to lazily match the inside part:

```
PCOMP((.|\n)*?)CQUAD4
```

By default, `*` is greedy, and will find the biggest match possible.